# Set private integer to another private integer

Tags: java, android, integer

How do you set the value of one private integer to another?
i.e:

```
private Integer [] mOne = {R.string.1, R.string.2};
```

to be-->

```
private Integer [] mTwo = {Integer mOne[]};
```

except that code doesn't work. the point being to have mTwo = {R.string.1,R.string.2} without having to explicitly write that...

I know what I want to say, just don't know how to say it! thanks for your help

Comment: I don't get it, what is `R.string.1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private Integer[] mTwo = mOne;
```

This creates a reference. If you need a copy:

```
private Integer[] mTwo = mOne.clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
private Integer [] mTwo = mOne;
```

Comment: Assuming the OP doesn't want a copy of the original array.

Comment: From what I could derive from "set one private integer to another"
It seemed as if he was just having trouble with array syntax.